# Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required error while installing a python module

Tags: python, visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015, python-3.8

I was trying to pip install netfilterqueue module with my Windows 7 system, in python 3.8
It returned an error "Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required"
My system already has got a Microsoft Visual C++ 14.25. Do I still need to install the 14.0, or is there a way that I can get out of this error?

If no, how do I install a lower version without uninstalling or replacing the higher version?

Comment: I have heard of a way to install a lower version of visual C++ by sort of inhibiting or hiding the existence of a higher version, and after installation bring it back to life. Do someone know about it?

Answer (score 1):

Alright, try uninstalling the higher version and go for the lower version making sure you download it with the same computer not with another, remembering that windows 7 no longer support some operations, and i will advice you upgrade to windows 10